when making fudge with Clover Condensed milk, how do I stop foaming?
I make fudge without any problems when using Nestle condensed milk, but when using Clover condensed milk, the mixture foams excessively and takes 15 minutes longer to reach the desired temperature, and the finished fudge contains small white crunchy pieces, like chalk. Clover CM contains more saturated fat, proteins and calcium than Nestle CM. How do I stop the foaming? I don't mind the extra cooking time, but maybe the extra cooking time causes the crunchy problem with the added calcium in Clover. Thanks, Jon.

The crunchy bits sounds like sugar nucleation crystals. Are the recipes the same for both fudges? See here for a similar problem
